# Prevent UI from freezing when using Task.Result

Tags: c#, .net, task

I am calling Task.Run(() => DoSomething()).Result which causes the UI to freeze and it happens because am using ".Result". I need Result because i want to return the value.

I don't want the Method StartSomething to be async because I don't want to await the method StartSomething. I want the await to happen at DoSomething().

So basically I need a asynchronous method to be called by a synchronous method, without freezing the UI. Plus I want to return the value from the async method to the top level that is on Button Click.

Can this code be improved or is there any other solution?

```
private TaskCompletionSource<bool> TaskCompletion = null;
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        bool k = StartSomething();
    }

    private bool StartSomething()
    {
        return Task.Run(() => DoSomething()).Result;
    }

    private async Task<bool> DoSomething()
    {
        TaskCompletion = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        await Task.WhenAny(TaskCompletion.Task, Task.Delay(3000));
        MessageBox.Show("DoSomething");
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: BackgroundWorker is your friend

Comment: If you want to learn Multtiasking, BackgroundWorker in a GUI technology like WindowsForms is what I advise as well. Tasks, Threads, Threadpools - all those are advanced techniques. You need to learn the basics before you try them.

Comment: `Task.Run(...).Result;`. I'm not going to say it's 100% always wrong. Maybe only 99.99999%. It's "Task system, please find a suitable thread to run this piece of code while I (the current thread) do something else. Now, before I can do anything else, I need the result of running that code to completion". It's the same outcome as just running that code yourself on your current thread but throws extra unnecessary machinery at it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method `StartSomething()` doesn't make sense to me. It starts a new `Task` and then just synchronously waits for the result (`.Result`) of this task, which is effectively useless - it is nearly ***[*]*** the same as calling `DoSomething()` directly. Also `DoSomething()` is already asynchronous so you don't need to start a new `Task` for it.

It looks like you don't need `StartSomething()` method at all. If you make `Button_Click` handler `async`, you can then simply `await DoSomething()` directly:

```
private TaskCompletionSource<bool> TaskCompletion = null;

private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    bool k = await DoSomething();
}

private async Task<bool> DoSomething()
{
    TaskCompletion = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    await Task.WhenAny(TaskCompletion.Task, Task.Delay(3000));
    MessageBox.Show("DoSomething");
    return true;
}
```

### Edit:

While using *async all the way down* solution (as shown above) is IMO the preferred way, if you really can't change calling code to `async`, I can think of two ways to call `async` method from synchronous method without blocking UI. First is to manually set up a continuation tasks like this:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DoSomething().ContinueWith((task) =>
        {
            bool k = task.Result;

            // use the result
        },

        // TaskScheduler argument is needed only if the continuation task
        // must run on the UI thread (eg. because it access UI elements).
        // Otherwise this argument can be omitted.
        TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

    // Method can exit before DoSomething().Result becomes
    // available, which keep UI responsive
}
```

So you basicly split synchronous method (one split instead of each `await`) into several parts (continuation lambda methods) linked by `.ContinueWith`. This is similar to what `await` does under a hood. Problem is that unlike `await` (which produces nice and clean code), your code will be full of these continuation lambdas. And it will get much worse when you add exception handling blocks, `using` blocks, etc.

The second approach is using nested loops, eg. Stephen Toub's [WaitWithNestedMessageLoop](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/04/13/should-i-expose-synchronous-wrappers-for-asynchronous-methods/) extension method:

```
static T WaitWithNestedMessageLoop<T>(this Task<T> task)
{
    var nested = new DispatcherFrame();
    task.ContinueWith(_ => nested.Continue = false, TaskScheduler.Default);
    Dispatcher.PushFrame(nested);
    return task.Result;
}
```

Nested loops are quite advanced technique (I actually never used it) and I don't recommend using it unless you have to.

---

***[*]*** There are differences in exception handling, executing thread, etc., but these are not relevant to this question.

Comment: You did exactly what I didn't want you to do. You made the buttonClick async. I don't want the method calling DoSomething to have an async modifier. @Ňuf

Comment: @JerinSebastian: Can you explain, why you don't want `async` `Button_Click`? Because if you want to call async method, the rule of thumb is [async all the way down](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx). And if you want to keep your UI responsinve, `async` is your best friend.

Comment: In my actual application, it won't be a button click event but a method, which will be called from many places. I don't want to specify async modifier everywhere I use.

Comment: @JerinSebastian: I added two ways to call async method from synchronous method without blocking UI. But IMO *"I don't want to specify async modifier"* is very poor argument when designing a software, especially if that `async` modifier is exactly what you need. But I understand that maybe you already have zillion lines of existing code and changing it all to async can be too costly and so sync-to-async call may be needed.