# How to get remote host status by using Connectivity Plugin 4.0?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, connectivity

I want to ping remote host and get his status I created function like this:

```
      public async  Task<Boolean> Connect_Test(string ip,int port)
    {
        var isReachable = await CrossConnectivity.Current.IsReachable(ip, port);
        if (isReachable == true)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
        }
```

I call this function like this:

```
          var connect = Connect_Test(adres_ip, 4210).Result;
           if (connect==true)
            {
      
              //Alert is reachable
            }
           else
            {
                //Alert not reachable
            }
```

My app freezes after executing this code and don't return value of of the remote host status.

Comment: Don't use `.Result`. If the call is asynchronous, always call it asynchronously, or if you can't see the options in eg [Prevent UI from freezing when using Task.Result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53332038/prevent-ui-from-freezing-when-using-task-result)

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I called it asynchronous and it helped with freezing but now  my return value is always false even if host is avalible. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used wrong method from connectivity plugin the correct one is IsRemoteReachable. Problem is solved.